# MonoTouch UITabBarController and UINavigationController Title

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

I have a UITabBarController with various views to navigate around my application.

I wish to add a nice title to the top of these and figured the nicest way is with the UINavigationController.

Found a nice article in xcode to do this: http://b00gizm.posterous.com/how-to-embed-a-navigation-controller-inside-a

Obviously tried following the article above with no luck... does anyone know how to do this on Mono using C#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to display titles on the top side of your views, it would be better to just create other views for this purpose alone.
The UINavigationController has a specific purpose and that is to provide navigation among various controllers in its stack, which means it will also need at least a root view controller.

Comment: Yea I actually kind of agree with you, it does seem like a mis-use. I shall accept this answer.

Comment: Can you point me in the direction of doing this? I'm having trouble finding an example. I keep trying to set `this.Title="The Title"` but it never shows up in the UITableViewController.

Comment: @robertmiles3: this.Title="The Title" will only work of the controller is part of a UINavigationController or a UITabBarController. In other situations, you will have to create your own view to put as title on the top side of the view.